# Can't boot Ubuntu properly after dual boot installation with Windows 10

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

I am trying to to install Ubuntu 18.0.4.1 alongside Windows 10.
I tried to install it more than once with many guides and YouTube videos, and each time I encountered a booting problem.

After installation, I can reach the GRUB menu and I have the option to start Windows or Ubuntu. I also have *Advanced Options for Ubuntu* available, and Windows runs ok, but if I choose to start Ubuntu, all I get is a black screen and some noise from the computer.

In the Advanced Options I have two versions of Ubuntu - one that ends with 38 and one that ends with 29 - and a recovery mode for each.

I tried to disable Secure boot and Fast boot. I disabled CSM / legacy mode.

In the installation, I tried to install normally or to partition myself, but nothing worked. I have a 128 GB SSD and a 1TB HDD. I tried to install it on the 1 TB drive but I have never tried to install it on the SSD disk (because I did not want ruin my Windows 10 installation).

Can anyone help with this?
I just can't imagine what would be the cause of the problem...

Comment: Do you have a Nvidia card? If so, press 'e' to edit whatever kernel you're trying to boot, add `nomodeset` to the line with "quiet splash". This will give you video. Then open Additional Drivers, select and install the recommended driver. Reboot and you should be fine now with the correct resolution.

Comment: thank you for your reply , i googled some of the phrases , i saw that this is a solution for a very similar problem to mine , can you please give abit more specific steps , : when do i need to press 'e'? , and what is the situation iam supposed to be in ? because i deleted ubunto so am i gonna need to re install it and then add the parameter nomodeset , or do i need to add it before the installation?

Comment: It's hard to be more specific than the above comment. You just need to understand what's happening - you haven't yet installed the Nvidia proprietary drivers *and* you card isn't correctly supported by the native open-source driver included (`nouveau`) - and how to use the `nomodeset`workaround - it forces a very "basic" video mode that is compatible with any card - that provides a GUI environment where it's easy to search for the "Additional Drivers" tool (like any other app/software) and with it easily install the graphics drivers you need. Once done it should work.

Comment: Some more details: http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it  See screen shots of grub menu & adding nomdoeset.

Answer (score 0):

Dont panic. You could use editor to grub, press 'e' before Enter over the option Ubuntu(grub menu). After you should write nomodeset at the end of line which says linux  and after boot. Sure, the installation is well done. Luck. If that doesnt work, you should search grub boot options.

If it is drivers problem, you could try to boot with knoppix and mount/chroot your ubuntu system.

http://www.knopper.net/knoppix-mirrors/index-en.html